# Можно ли для каждого контроллера создавать отдельный ресурс?

Tags: laravel, resources

Имеются несколько запросов, обращающихся к одной таблице. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли создать для каждого из этих запросов свой отдельный класс-ресурс(API-resouce) с определенным выводом, т.е. один запрос выводит значения полей "id", "name" и "email", а другой запрос значения полей "id" и "name"? Или для всех запросов одной таблицы должен быть какой то один api-resource и в нем менять вариации выбора полей, значения которых будут выводиться. Например: таблица #1 - USER с полями: id, surname, name, work_id, таблица #2 - Work с полями: id, title. В одном запросе нужно сделать select из USER и WORK, используя eloquent и вывести такие поля: USER.surname, USER.name, WORK.title. Во втором запросе нужно сделать select из USER: id, surname, name. И в выводе использовать один RESOURCE, например USERRESOURCE

```
public class UserResource 
{
   public function toArray($request)
   {
    return [
      'id'=>$this->id,
      'name'=>$this->name,
      'surname=>$this->surname'
     ]
   }
}

public class WorkResource 
{
   public function toArray($request)
   {
    return [
      'id'=>$this->id,
      'title'=>$this->title
     ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос. Хотя работаю с Laravel, но я после трех прочтений так и не понял, что Вы имеете в виду. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править", воспользуйтесь ей. И ознакомьтесь с [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) перед редактированием.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Естественно, можно. Рассматривайте Resource как частный случай модели. Вам, я думаю, известно, что для одних и тех же данных в зависимости от задачи и конкретных условий применения можно использовать различные модели. Например, для данных о пользователе обычно используется модель, отражающая все данные пользователя, за исключением пароля или его хэша. Но при авторизации можно применить альтернативную модель, которая умеет выполнить операцию хэширования пароля и сверки полученного хэша с сохраненным эталоном, но ничего не знает про его биографию, номера телефонов и прочие несущественные для авторизации детали. Такое разделение моделей пользователя позволяет повысить безопасность системы и ее быстродействие в целом.

Так и в Вашем случае. Для различных операций API Вы можете совершенно спокойно использовать как различные варианты моделей, так и различные варианты ресурсов для одних и тех же данных. Все зависит от Ваших целей.

Comment: Another approach may be creating a resource for each request but, in my opinion, this will break the DRY principle [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011647/how-to-hide-relationships-column-in-eloquent)

Comment: А никто и не предлагает повторяться. Просто это как _кирпич_ (данные). Когда Вы кладете из него несущую стену - Вам нужно, чтобы он был _широкий_, и Вы кладете его плашмя. А когда возводите перестенок - нужно, чтобы он был _узкий_, и Вы кладете его на ребро. В исключительном случае Вам нужно заткнуть дырку, и Вы _откалываете от кирпича половину_. При это _кирпич_ все тот же, и я не предлагаю Вам каждый _кирпич_ обрабатывать напильником для идеального качества стенки - стенку Вы потом оштукатурите. Я предлагаю использовать три _модели_ кирпича, а _штукатурка_ - во фронтенде.

Comment: Перестенков может быть много и разных. Но _кирпич_ во всех из них кладется на ребро. Несущих стен также больше одной. И в каждой из них _кирпич_ кладется плашмя. В итоге 2 модели используются для предоставления данных куда более чем в 2 типах запросов. Да и дырок может быть больше одной, и _половинка кирпича_ также используется более чем в одном случае. Так что и с DRY тут будет все в порядке, и _кирпич_ будет заточен под задачу.